# Onclick radio buttons run its respective mysql query and display it in a table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, filter

I've been searching a whole day for this code but no luck, I came across a code while googling obvious it was not working, so I edited it in my own way , but still I had no luck in getting it to actually work, So please guys I would be very happy if someone helps me with this code.

What I want is when I select a radio button and hit enter the next page I see should display my database data according to the radio button.. ITS LIKE A DATABASE FILTER which filter outs my database data..

So first of all here's the first page.....   `FILTERPAGE.HTML`

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>FILTER PAGE</title>
</head>

<body>
<form action="search.php" method="post" name="filter_option">
<table width="100%" border="0">
    <tr>
    <td>
    <label>
        <input name="filter_options" type="radio" id="filter_options_0" value="default_filter" checked>
       Default</label>
    </td>
      <td><label>
        <input type="radio" name="filter_options" value="special_id_filter" id="filter_options_1">
        Special ID</label></td>
      <td><label>
        <input type="radio" name="filter_options" value="company_name_filter" id="filter_options_2">
        Company Name</label></td>
      <td><label>
        <input type="radio" name="filter_options" value="brand_name_filter" id="filter_options_3">
        Brand Name</label></td>
      <td><label>
        <input type="radio" name="filter_options" value="model_id_filter" id="filter_options_4">
        Model ID</label></td>
      <td><label>
        <input type="radio" name="filter_options" value="colour_filter" id="filter_options_5">
        Colour</label></td>
      <td><label>
        <input type="radio" name="filter_options" value="size_filter" id="filter_options_6">
        Size</label></td>
      <td><label>
        <input type="radio" name="filter_options" value="frame_type_filter" id="filter_options_7">
        Frame Type</label></td>
      <td><label>
        <input type="radio" name="filter_options" value="frame_for_filter" id="filter_options_8">
        Frame For</label></td>
      <td><label>
        <input type="radio" name="filter_options" value="quantity_filter" id="filter_options_9">
        Quantity</label></td>
      <td><label>
        <input type="radio" name="filter_options" value="price_filter" id="filter_options_10">
        Price</label></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input name="submit" type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And Now here's the Second One which is the PHP Stuff..........   `SEARCH.PHP`

```
<?php 
 mysql_connect("localhost","root","password") or die(mysql_error());

 mysql_select_db("stock_entry") or die(mysql_error());

$filteroption= $_POST['filter_options'];

//To use different queries while searching

if ($filteroption == 'default_filter')
{
$queres = "SELECT * FROM stock_entry_spectacles ORDER BY 'id'";
}
else if ($filteroption == 'special_id_filter')
{
$queres = "SELECT * FROM stock_entry_spectacles ORDER BY 'special_id'";
}
else if ($filteroption == 'company_name_filter')
{
$queres = "SELECT * FROM stock_entry_spectacles ORDER BY 'company_name'";
}
else if ($filteroption == 'brand_name_filter')
{
$queres = "SELECT * FROM stock_entry_spectacles ORDER BY 'brand_name'";
}
else if ($filteroption == 'model_id_filter')
{
$queres = "SELECT * FROM stock_entry_spectacles ORDER BY 'model_id'";
}

$query = $queres;
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<table class='data' border='0' cellspacing='2' align='center'>
 <tr>
 <td align='center' class='special_id'><input type='text' name='id' value='".$row['special_id']."'></td>
 <td align='center' class='company_nametd'><input type='text' name='company_name' value='".$row['company_name']."'></td>
  <td align='center' class='brand_namestd'> <input type='text' name='brand_name' value='".$row['brand_name']."'></td>
 <td align='center' class='model_idtd'> <input type='text' name='model_id' value='".$row['model_id']."'></td>
 <td align='center' class='colour_selecttd'> <input type='text' name='colour_select' value='".$row['colour_select']."'></td>
 <td align='center' class='size_selecttd'> <input type='text' name='size_select' value='".$row['size_select']."'></td>
 <td align='center' class='type_selecttd'><input type='text' name='type_select' value='".$row['type_select']."'></td>
 <td align='center' class='for_selecttd'> <input type='text' name='for_select' value='".$row['for_select']."'></td>
 <td align='center' class='quantitytd'> <input type='text' name='quantity' value='".$row['quantity']."'></td>
 <td align='center' class='pricetd'> <input type='text' name='price' value='".$row['price']."'></td>
 <tr>
 </table>";
 }  

?>
```

And the Last but not the least the Mysql Structure......

Database Name: `stock_entry`

Table structure for table `stock_entry_spectacles`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `stock_entry_spectacles` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `special_id` int(225) DEFAULT NULL,
  `company_name` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `brand_name` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `model_id` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_polish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `colour_select` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `size_select` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type_select` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `for_select` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `quantity` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` int(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;
```

Dumping data for table `stock_entry_spectacles`

```
INSERT INTO `stock_entry_spectacles` (`id`, `special_id`, `company_name`, `brand_name`, `model_id`, `colour_select`, `size_select`, `type_select`, `for_select`, `quantity`, `price`) VALUES
(1, NULL, 'Titan', 'abc', '123', 'GunMetal', 50, 'Metal', 'Male', 2, NULL),
(2, NULL, 'AO Specs', 'def', '456', 'Black', 48, 'Metal', 'Male', 6, 500),
(3, NULL, 'Sinora', 'ghi', '789', 'Blue', 13, 'broad sided', 'Female', 3, 460),
(4, NULL, 'Tommy', 'jkl', '963', 'GunMetal', 40, 'Shell', 'Male', 8, 800),
(5, 14873273, 'Manav', 'mno', '852', 'Black', 50, 'Metal', 'Male', 5, 120);
```

Please anyone try to help me as I needed this code for one of my projects....

Comment: why `@` before `mysql_query`.?

Comment: don't know, it had before i think...

Comment: i removed it now... please help dipesh if u can

Comment: What is the error you get exactly?

Comment: what the final result you got ?

Comment: I need to know if this code is working properly or no???

Answer (score 0):

**Replace**

```
mysql_connect("localhost","root","password") or die(mysql_error());
```

**With**

```
mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());
```